# updating the gridview as well as database on click of a button after changing value of a textbox in a cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new bee, I need help on following grid view issue.
I have a gridview and all its cells are text boxes and there is a button outside, clicking upon which have to save data to database and update the gridview as well(Changes to the textboxes has to be saved in database and grid should be refreshed with changed data).

Comment: how do you populate your datagrid?

Comment: I have a datasource and each text box in grid view is populated by "Eval("name")" using databind().

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do above is to make a function i.e. loadGrid() that will populate the grid, and you can call it anywhere like in button_click event or it may be the Text_Validated event.

And try to explain your question and decorate it with your code.

Welcome to Stackoverflow !

Answer (score 0):

Computers don't assume anything, you have to tell it exactly what you need it to do.

You'll need to have a function somewhere in your program that takes arguments and then passes those arguments as parameters to a database. When you click your button, read the values from your gridview cell text boxes, and pass those values as arguments to your function.

Code might look something like:

```
public void UpdateUser(int userId, string userName, string userDescription){
   // code to update database here
}

public void button1_OnClick(object obj, EventArguments e)
{
     UpdateUser(txtBoxUserID.Content, txtBoxNewUsername.Content, txtBoxUserDescription.Content);
     UpdateDatagrid();
}
```

That code isn't going to work, it's an example off the top of my head. Although the principle behind it is how you need to approach your problem. Hope that helps.